# Fazendo um factory retornar os dados de uma requisição Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, web-service

Estou tentando fazer uma *factory* que retorne o JSON de uma requisição Ajax que eu estou fazendo, só que, acho que pelo fato de ser assíncrona, o container com os usuários volta sempre vazio. Tanto que testei com vários `console.log` e a sequência das chamadas era diferente.

**Resumindo**: qual recurso posso usar para que a factory preencha os dados da requisição antes de retornar para que assim ele não volte vazio?

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso você pode implementar uma Promises, com isso você consegue pegar o retorno da request.

exemplo de implementação.

```
.factory('servico', function['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {

    return {
       method: function (objeto) {

           var deferred : $q.defer();
           $http.post('url', objeto)
           .success(function(data){
             deferred.resolve(data);
           }).error(function(data) {
             deferred.reject(data);
           });         
          deferred.promise;
       }
    }
}])
```

no seu controller que injeta seu factory você vai acessar da seguinte forma a promises

```
servico.method({objeto}).then(function(retorno){ $scope.suaVariavel = retorno }, function(retornoError){});
```

o Factory Serviço, fica responsável por realizar a request HTTP (ajax) e devolver se SUCESSO, o seu objeto, e se erro, o seu erro, com isso a promise deferred, fica responsável por lançar um (resolve ou reject) de acordo com a request http.
no seu controller onde você injetou o serviço, dentro do Then você pega o retorno da promises, implementada no serviço e aplica p/ sua propriedade.

Referência de promises/Defered
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q